# user.has_perm is false even though I can see it both in admin page and user.user_permissions

Tags: django, python-3.x, user-permissions

I am trying to test a permission. The code for permission is this in 
 "customAuth.permissions.py"

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Soru)  
can_see_soru_list = Permission.objects.create(
        codename="can_see_soru_list",
        name="Can See The List",
        content_type=content_type,
)
```

I have a customUser model that is almost same as normal User object.

```
class customUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The problem is, I added the permission to an instance of "customUser" in shell and checked it with `user.has_perm("can_see_soru_list")`. This returned `False`. Although, if I check it with `user.user_permissions.all()` I can see the permission object there and even call it to an instance like `perm = user.user_permissions.all()[0]`.

Why `has_perm()` function return false is what I don't understand.

Here is what I get in `python manage.py shell`:

```
>>> user = customUser.objects.get(username="testuser1")
>>> user.has_perm("can_see_soru_list")
False
>>> user.user_permissions.all()
<QuerySet [<Permission: soruweb | soru | Can See The List>]>
>>> user.user_permissions.all()[0]
<Permission: soruweb | soru | Can See The List>
>>> perm = user.user_permissions.all()[0]
>>> perm.codename
'can_see_soru_list'
>>> p = Permission.objects.get(codename="can_see_soru_list", content_type=c)
>>> p == perm
True
```

Quick edit: I tried clearing cache with `delattr(user,"_perm_cache")` or something like that and I tried getting the user object from database again, at first within the same shell, second time opened new one and tried at it. No luck there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the right thing to `has_perm`. As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) state, you need to pass `"<app label>.<permission codename>`". So:

```
user.has_perm("soruweb.can_see_soru_list")
```

Comment: Thanks you, that worked well but I don't understand. I added the permission under "customAuth" app, permissions.py folder. customUser model is also in "customAuth" app. But somehow permission flied to "soruweb" app. Why?

Comment: Because it's attached to the Soru object, which is presumably defined in that app. Still, the main issue was that you were not passing any app label at all.

Comment: Yeah, I tried "customAuth.can_see_soru_list" but never did it with "soruweb". Thank you again.